# Getting Error: Package "single-spa-angular" has no builders defined. After migration from Angular 6 to Angular 12

Tags: angular, single-page-application, single-spa-angular

I have migrate my  angular 6 (Micro app) to angular 12,
but now i am getting this error

```
[error] Error: Package "single-spa-angular" has no builders defined.
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/Users/app-path/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:118:19)
    at BuildCommand.initialize (/Users/app-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:145:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async BuildCommand.validateAndRun (/Users/app-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:121:22)
    at async Object.runCommand (/Users/app-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:224:24)
    at async default_1 (/Users/app-path/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:70:31)
```

I am using latest version of SPA lib
"single-spa": "^5.9.2",
"single-spa-angular": "^5.0.2",

Can some one please help me to fix this issue..... or any specific article which i can refer...

Answer (score 0):

you need to install @angular-builders/custom-webpack as dev dependency

```
npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack -D
```